# Floating Point - Avoiding Overflow and Underflow

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm reading an article that provides tips for handling floating point arithmetic.
One of the examples given is for the computation of:

$$S = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+...x_n^2}$$

The trick is to compute $x_{max} = max(\vert x_1 \vert, \vert x_2 \vert,, ..., \vert x_n \vert)$ and then compute:

$$S = x_{max}\sqrt{\left(\frac{x_1}{x_{max}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x_2}{x_{max}}\right)^2+...+\left(\frac{x_n}{x_{max}}\right)^2}$$

This certainly avoids overflow when computing the squares of the elements.
But by dividing by $x_{max}$, isn't there a risk that the computations of the squares would now underflow?

If so, is there some further trick to avoid the underflow?

Comment: There are many things that can happen. Loss of precision too. Not to speak of how extremely slow division is on modern CPUs.

Comment: The point is that those quotients that underflow are not relevant anyway. If $x_1/x_2$ can only be represented by $0$, then $\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ is just $|x_1|$, which is what you obtain by $|x_1|\sqrt{1+(x_2/x_1)^2}$. If the sum of squares has many terms then you might need to use [techniques to cut down the error of the sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) too.

Comment: You could divide by some least common or least mean $2^k$ multiple instead. Would just subtract from the exponent equally which is a very simple operation on floating point numbers. You could do it by hand in software by bit operations or if it exists in hardware.

Comment: Also you wont get any loss of precision in the mantissas when dividing by a power of 2 instead of a general floating point division.

Comment: Is this a problem you actually have? The max double precision number is $10^{308}$, so your problem occurs when $S \sim 10^{154}$. It seems like if you are computing a floating point number this large, many other bad things have happened.

Comment: @user14717 This is a theoretical exercise not a practical one. In practice, your are right that the issue is unlikely to occur. Also if it does, it's only a problem if the m x n matrix is very large with elements close to zero.